# Don't work ide-haskell for atomeditor

Tags: haskell, atom-editor

I tried to install [atom](https://atom.io/packages/ide-haskell).
I go to Properties->packages and then find ide-haskell and then install them. But it doesn't work. On the main page of ide-haskell author wrote that in `~/.atom/config.scon` should be section named "ide-haskell", but i can't find it. What i missed? What I should do to run ide-haskell?

My OS Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: have you installed ghc-mod on your system?

Comment: Yes , i install it , sorry that i answer late

Comment: OH , sorry , i anderstand, i should make a project (whith License) to run this addon)